# how to retrieve values from the dropdown in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this piece of code of dropdown,
like this there are more than 1 dropdown,
from which i want to get the name of each drop down and its selected value

```
<div style="display: inline-block;" class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Front-Desk<span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#"> 0</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Empty Values</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

for example: for the above code angularjs should return me 'Front-Desk' with its selected value '2'(say). 
If there is solution from JQuery then also i would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understood what you want, so your html code should be like below:

```html
<div style="display: inline-block;" class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-click="name='Back-Desk'">Back-Desk<span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu ">
            <li ng-click="getValue(0)"><a><span> 0</span></a></li>
            <li ng-click="getValue(1)"><a><span> 1</span></a></li>
            <li ng-click="getValue(2)"><a><span> 2</span></a></li>
            <li ng-click="getValue(3)"><a><span> 3</span></a></li>
            <li ng-click="getValue('Empty Values')"><a><span> Empty Values</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

and your controller should contain this function

```js
    $scope.getValue = function(value) {
        console.log("this is value:",$scope.name, value);
    }
```

Comment: yeah, I exactly wanted to do this. Thanks mate for the help

Comment: actually, I have total 10 dropdowns like this and for each dropdown, I cannot make separate 10 functions. Is there any way that I can get the dropdown name and value of all 10 in a single function?

Comment: yes you can use this function for all drop down just duplicate your html and use another name for button click

Comment: yeah, I figured it out, but then also I appreciate the help. @Mozhdeh.Hamidi

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think you are new in angular btw:

```
    <div style="display: inline-block;" class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Front-Desk<span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#"><span ng-model="value"> 0</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span ng-model="value"> 1</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span ng-model="value"> 2</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span ng-model="value"> 3</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span ng-model="value"> Empty Values</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In controller you have to declare a variable "$scope.value" in which your selected value will come.

Comment: i declared $scope.value as global in the controller, but then also am not able to see output in console.log()

Comment: When you select value from dropdown you need to call function in which you console the value.

`      <li><a href="#" ng-click= "clicked(value)"><span ng-model="value"> 0</span></a></li>
`
In controller you can check the value.

Comment: yes, i have kept a button, upon clicked there is a function running, inside the function i have put console.log()

Comment: $("#getdata").click(function(){
        console.log($scope.value);
    });

Comment: i used your way still no success.

Comment: Just create a fiddle and share with me.

Comment: Where is angular controller in your fiddle?